# PHP Creating New Instance of a Class Returns NULL

Tags: php

I'm currently creating a really simplistic online ordering website as part of a school project.  I am running into an issue where my controller tries to create an instance of a class that interfaces with my order parameters, but creating the new instance simply returns NULL.  When the page where the operation is called loads, I receive this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getParameters() on null in /home/data/www/z1785732/public_html/467/PlaceOrderController.php on line 31

Here are the files I'm working with:

This is the controller.  The specific class that is returning NULL is ParameterInterface.

```
<?php

include 'ItemDB.php';
include 'OrderDB.php';
include 'ccInterface.php';
include 'ParameterInterface.php';

class PlaceOrderController {
    var $itemDB;
    var $parameter;
    var $orderDB;
    var $ccInterface;

    function __construct() {
            $this->itemDB = new ItemDatabase();
            $this->ccInterface = new ccInterface();
            $this->parameter = new ParameterInterface();
    }
    public function displayCatalog() {
            return $this->itemDB->displayCatalog();
    }

    public function searchItem($itemNum) {
            return $this->itemDB->searchItem($itemNum);
    }

    public function getParameters() {
            return $this->parameter->getParameters();
    }

    public function addOrder() {
            $this->orderDB->addOrder($array1, $array2);
    }

    public function ccAuthorize($ccInfo) {
            return $this->ccInterface->ccAuthorize($ccInfo);
    }
}
?>
```

Here is ParameterInterface.php, where the function is defined.

```
<?php
class ParameterInterface {

    function connect() {

    $servername = '';
    $dbname='';
    $username = '';
    $password = '';

    try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Connection failed: ". $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $conn;

    }

    public function getParameters() {
            $conn = $this->connect();

            $query = "SELECT * FROM Admin;";
            $result = $conn->query($query);

            $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $row;
    }
}
?>
```

I'm hoping it's just something simple that my eyes aren't catching.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it should works. is `include 'ParameterInterface.php';` require the _right_ `ParameterInterface.php` file?

Comment: Yeah, I triple checked that my include and spelling were correct.  For testing, I wrote a quick test program, which successfully creates a class, and is able to get the information.

    `<?php
        include 'ParameterInterface.php';

        $parameter = new ParameterInterface();

       $row= $parameter->getParameters();
        echo $row['Shipping'];
        echo $row['Tax'];
    ?>`
From what I can tell, this is basically the same as the above code, but this works, while above it returns the error.

Comment: ... are you using php >= 5, yeah? can you put a `$this->parameter = new ParameterInterface(); var_dump($this->parameter );` in the construct and check the output?

Comment: also, let's see how you create an instance of `PlaceOrderController`. Aren't you call it in a static context, are you?

Comment: Yeah, just double checked, version 5.6.20-0

Comment: I see you removed them for public web. Good. Are you able to do any queries at all? You may want to also add another "catch" block for all other (Non-PDO) errors to see what may be happening.

Comment: Here is how I create the PlaceOrderController

`if (!isset($_SESSION['controller'])) {
        $_SESSION['controller'] = new PlaceOrderController;
        logger("New controller created");
}
`

Comment: Adam T, no, in my code they are filled in.  I simply removed them for this post.

Comment: Can you serialize `PlaceOrderController`? My guess is no. Take a look to `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()` anyway, and keep in mind that you can't serialize a PDO object.

Comment: I'm sorry, as I said, this is for a school project.  This is the first semester I've worked with PHP and MySQL, so my knowledge of coding is still very limited.  I'm not familiar with serializing.

Is that something that would affect one class and not another?  As I said, other classes, such as ItemDatabase are implemented in the same way, and create just fine.

Comment: Is this as simple as you have not set the values of the variables used in your `new PDO(...)` i.e. ` $servername = '';  $dbname='';  $username = '';  $password = '';`

Comment: RiggsFolly, no, as I addressed in an earlier comment, those were removed for this post, so as not to put them out there, but they are in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `Serializable` interface to be able to serialize your controller in session:

```
class PlaceOrderController implements Serializable
{

    // ... 

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->itemDB,
            $this->parameter,
            $this->orderDB,
            $this->ccInterface
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list(
            $this->itemDB,
            $this->parameter,
            $this->orderDB,
            $this->ccInterface
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    // ... 
}
```

Remember to start a new session after you do this. (clear your cookie) You may using an old `PlaceOrderController` object, with no propriety, in your current session.

Also, you may want rethink about this whole script. This isn't Java. Why you want store `PlaceOrderController` in session?

Comment: Yeah, ultimately, I think your final comment is the best idea.  This was a class project for a software design class that focuses on object oriented programming, so the teacher wanted us to use an object oriented style on our software (this is just the web interface, there are other interfaces done in C#).  He offered an example, and I modeled this after his example.  However, at the end of the day, working code is better than non-working code.  So I think I'll just scrap this, and redo it in much more straightforward php style.

Thank you for your assistance, Federico.

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems clean enough to me... however; depending on the version of PHP you are using, the **var** Keyword might not be ideal here since it means **Public**. If your Member Variables are Public; getters and setters are really more or less not that necessary as such.

Back to the Issue. *I would suggest taking a look at the name of the File:* ***ParameterInterface.php*** because it may not have been properly included which might be a Typo or so in the Filename. Be mindful of cases (Upper & Lower - depending on your Operating System). Try first checking if the file exist to see what you get; like so:

```
    <?php
        if(file_exist("ParameterInterface.php")){
            include "ParameterInterface.php";
            die ("Sure, ParameterInterface.php exists and it has been included...");                
        }else{
            die("Ah haaaa! Gotcha!!! So, 'ParameterInterface.php' does not exist in the current Directory....");
        }
        //AFTER THIS QUIRK DEBUGGING... YOU MIGHT JUST KNOW MORE...
```

**Would You mind to try redefining your Class, instead? Like so:**

```
    <?php
        class ParameterInterface {
            /**
             * @var PDO $CON_LINK
             */
            protected static $CON_LINK;

            //WOULDN'T HURT TO ADD AN EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR... NOW, WOULD IT?
            function __construct(){
                $servername         = '';
                $dbname             = '';
                $username           = '';
                $password           = '';

                if(!self::$CON_LINK) {
                    try {
                        self::$CON_LINK = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                        self::$CON_LINK->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                }

            }

            function connect() {
                return self::$CON_LINK;
            }

            public function getParameters() {
                $conn = $this->connect();

                $query = "SELECT * FROM Admin;";
                $result = $conn->query($query);

                $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                return $row;
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Hope this helps a little...

Comment: This was a great idea.  I added into the controller, and it did give me a response saying that ParameterInterface.php was found and included.

Unfortunately, I am still having the same error.  So it seems that the problem is not with the include, but rather the actual construction of the class.

Comment: ... the actual **CONSTRUCT**ion of the Class.... Now we know more... Although we know Constructors are implicitly defined; why not officially **__construct()** the Class by giving it an own constructor?

Comment: I added in an empty constructor and am still getting the same error.  It wasn't in there originally because the other interfaces didn't have one, and they constructed properly, so I figured this one wouldn't need it either.

Thanks for the suggestion, though

Comment: I tried your class redefinition, but I still got the same error.  I have decided to abandon this object oriented way of doing it, and simply just have the necessary functions in the pages that call them.  It's not exactly what the assignment called for, but I decided it's more important to have a working site.

Thank you for your help, though.  Much appreciated!